# NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdeveloper

I'm trying to deploy Spring-boot microservice application from Jdeveloper 12c to Weblogic. And, I've encountered a deployment issue from Maven.  I already include "javax.validation" library to pom.xml.  But, it still complains about NoSuchMethodError:

> javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName

POM.XML:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <!--scope>test</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <!--scope>test</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>c:\My library\ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of springboot

try this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

insteed of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Using Spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE.  It's already having javaee-api 8.0 in pom.xml.  -thanks